# While, do, done flow control in bash

Tags: bash, loops, while-loop, ifs

Can anyone explain the control flow of the following bash script?

```
while IFS= read -r file
do 
rm -rf "$file"
done < todelete.txt
```

From what I understand, this would happen:

IFS would be assigned nothing.
The rm -rf command would do nothing because its argument, the variable $file, is blank/empty/nothing.
The two previous steps would then repeat indefinitely.

Clearly this is not the case, because the script works as expected; it deletes all files listed in todelete.txt.

I believe the explanation lies in "done < todelete.txt" but I don't understand what's happening there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect after `done` affects `read`'s input stream. So `read` will work on the contents of `todelete.txt` rather than `stdin`.

You should read the [Internal Commands](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html) section of the Bash manual for more info. (Browse directly to example 15-7.)

Answer (score 2):

The whole `while ... done` is treated as single command, which is fed a `todelete.txt` file on its input.

The `while IFS= read -r file` thing reads the lines from this input file until the `EOF`, assigning each line to `$file` variable, and each iteration of the loop removes that file.